# Having Connection String for Development and Production

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC project written in C# which uses a SQL Server database. I have my connection string in `appsettings.json` and it is set to my local database.

My problem is when I publish my application the SQL Server is going to have a different name. How can I have a connection string for development and for production?

I have searched the internet for days and tried various things but nothing seems to work.

Many thanks for any help,

Comment: Google for asp.net core Config transformations

Comment: Thanks but I am using asp.net core.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create file named `appsettings.development.json` in the same folder that standard `appsettings.json` is located.
Content of this file should be 1-1 copy of original appsettings.
In original `appsettings` modify the connection string, so it will point to ***live*** database. You can remove unused settings that will not be changed for production environment from `appsettings.development.json`.

Set Your production server's `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` system variable to `Production` (optional, at least in theory).

You will find more info in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: Thank you. This is my first web app I am about to publish and just realised I can change the connection string in the publish config. I think this is where I change it and then it will use this connection string every time I publish my app.

Comment: *Content of this file should be 1-1 copy of original appsettings* - it's applied over the top of the base so you only need it to contain the changes

Comment: Yest - that's why there is a `You can remove unused settings that will not be changed for production environment from appsettings.development.json.` in my answear. It is a step-by-step for beginner, I think it's easier this way.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I created a appsettings.production and put the remote details in there and it worked great. Thanks again.